# SQL Server 2016 distinct and trim not removing left empty space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT(line_of_bus)
    FROM contract_info 
    WHERE line_of_bus IS NOT NULL 
      AND TRIM(line_of_bus) <> '' 
      AND contract_yr = i_year
END
```

I have a value that has a left trailing space ' value' and it is a duplicate. Trim does not seem to work and distinct is not removing the duplicate. I've tried using `ltrim` and `rtrim` but they don't seem to work, any workarounds or hints would be highly appreciated. I'm using SQL Server 2016

Comment: First you would need to SELECT distinct( ltrim( rtrim( line_of_bus ) ) ).   Second: are they trailing spaces or other control characters like CRLF, TAB etc ?

Comment: can youi provide a [mre] see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `trim` is not a function in SQL Server 2016, if you check the documentation it states *Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later*. What does "don't seem to work" actually mean? Show us.

Comment: John, you answered my question, I had made the mistake of not wrapping the ltrim, and rtrim inside the distinct. Do you want to answer it so that I can mark it as answered?

Comment: yeah, sorry guys next time I will make sure to follow the minimal reproducible example

Comment: Checking for `line_of_bus IS NOT NULL` is redundant because when `line_of_bus` IS NULL then `TRIM(line_of_bus) <> ''` (or `RTRIM/LTRIM`) won't be `TRUE` either.